# Is it possible to Automate and scrape data from an Android APK Without using a mobile device?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, web-scraping, automation

I would like to scrape data from an Android APK. Where data will be refreshed at every Hour. So the Refresh button also have to be Automated

Answer (score 0):

*You can use the following command to clear the data from particular application  :*

```
adb shell pm clear packageName
```